# obtener variable desde archivo php importarla y usarla en ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

tengo un archivo php con el siguiente contenido

```
----filename.php---

<?php
$text = 'eos';
?>
```

y tengo un archivo js que se llama app.js con el siguiente contenido

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/swapngo.org/proyecta_json.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var tiempo = [];
            var coin = [];


            for(var i in data) {
                tiempo.push("Date " + data[i].tiempo);
                coin.push(data[i].VARIABLE-PHP);
            }

var chartdata = {
                labels: tiempo,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Coin', 
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 153, 224)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: coin
                    }
                ]
            };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Que solucion podria utilizar para poder transportar el valor de la variable $text en el archivo php y usarla en mi codigo ajax. Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Gracias

---

Edito mi pregunta para mostrarles  con mas detalle lo que trato de lograr

```
// peticion ajax 
var url = "otro.php";
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "GET",
success: function (respuesta) { 
    console.log(respuesta);
}
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/swapngo.org/proyecta_json.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var tiempo = [];
        var coin = [];


        for(var i in data) {
            tiempo.push("Date " + data[i].tiempo);
            coin.push(data[i].console.log(respuesta));  <------
        }

var chartdata = {
            labels: tiempo,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'Coin', 
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 153, 224)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: coin
                }
            ]
        };

    var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

Deseo colocar el valor que obtuve de la consulta AJAX alli para poder generar la Grafica.Gracias agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: pero en el ajax vas a otro archivo diferente... vas a [proyecta_json.php] en ves de [filename.php] ?

Comment: es cierto voy http://127.0.0.1/swapngo.org/proyecta_json.php

por que alli tengo la data en formato json la data que tengo alli esta formatiada de la siguiente forma 

0 
tiempo "2018-07-30 18:25:01"
eos "-1.01"
1 
tiempo "2018-07-30 18:30:01"
eos "-1.14"
2 
tiempo "2018-07-30 18:35:01"
eos "-1.08"

pero el dato que dice EOS cambia segun el input que viene de un form

si existe la forma de tomarlo de ese json tambien seria una buena solucion. Gracias

Comment: osea son dos archivos direferentes >?

Comment: bueno, no me contestas si son dos archivos diferentes entonces lo bueno seria que hicieras otra llamada ajax a ese archivo, o debes pegar algo mas de codigo para entender mejor

Comment: Si correcto son dos archivos diferentes en proyecta_json.php tengo la data formatiada en JSON que tomo para hacer una grafica 
en filename.php tengo la variable que me sirve o serviria para generar  la grafica con el dataset correcto sin necesidad de colocarlo manualmente.

Comment: bueno como dije anterior mente, lo mejor es que hagas dos peticiones de ajax para cada archivo y asi capturas las variables o de otra forma combinas los archivos y metes la misma variable en el JSON

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo por favor ?

Comment: Ya probaste a incluir el archivo? **include 'filename.php';**

Comment: bueno, ahi abajo te dieron un ejemplo @Rafuch0, te sirvio ?

Comment: si me sirvio pero edite la pregunta con mas detalle y el nuevo codigo incrustado lo que deseo es imprimir el valor de la variable en ese punto especifico que he marcado.

Answer (score 5):

Para recoger una variable de PHP en un AJAX basta con que hagas un simple 'echo ' de esta variable, aqui tienes un ejemplo de :
 
**Peticion GET simple:**

```
// peticion ajax 
var url = "filename.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (respuesta) { 
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
});
```

En  `filename.php`:

```
<?php
    $texto = "Texto mandando desde PHP";
    echo $texto; 
?>
```

---

También puedes puedes mandar datos en un `POST` y dependiendo de ello mandar respuestas diferentes:

 **Mandar parametros mediante POST:**

```
// peticion ajax 
var url = "filename.php";
var enviarVariable = "dia";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { "parametro1":enviarVariable },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (respuesta) { 
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
});
```

En `filename.php`:

```
<?php
    $paramentro = $_POST["parametro1"];
    if($paramentro=="dia"){
        echo "Abierto";
    } else {
        echo "Cerrado";
    }
?>
```

---

Y ya si necesitas:

**Mandar un ARRAY en formato JSON:**

 Para poder devolver un array en formato JSON tienes que convertirlo a la hora de enviarlo en `filename.php`;

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Y preparar el AJAX para recibirlo, añadiendo el parámetro a la petición AJAX:

```
dataType: "json"
```

> Solo podrás mandar en formato JSON si es a la misma maquina, las peticiones AJAX que van fuera de la maquina tienen problema de *cross-domain* por lo que están restringidas por defecto por el navegador por lo que hace falta usar el formato **[JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp)**

Comment: OK eso funciono.

Answer (score 0):

lo que hice al final fue separar todo el conjunto de archivos los php que capturan la data y la expulsan en json format corren por con cron  y se muestra por separado la gráfica en el php que la solicita usando unos if que condicionan la entrada del user se separa todo el cojunto de gráficas dependiendo de las opción.