# ¿Como exactamente funciona '$.ajax({type, post, data})' en este conexto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen día, soy un estudiante entrando en el mundo de la programación tratando de figurar como exactamente funciona el script y me vendría bien una ayuda por favor, gracias.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.error').hide();

$("#enviar-btn").click(function() {

    //Obtenemos el valor del campo nombre
    var name = $("input#name").val();

    //Validamos el campo nombre, simplemente miramos que no esté vacío
    if (name == "") {
        $("label#name_error").show();
        $("input#name").focus();
        return false;
    }

    //Obtenemos el valor del campo password
    var password = $("input#password").val();

    //Validamos el campo password, simplemente miramos que no esté vacío
    if (password == "") {
        $("label#pass_error").show();
        $("input#password").focus();
        return false;
    }

    //Construimos la variable que se guardará en el data del Ajax para pasar al archivo php que procesará los datos
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&password=' + password;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#register_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Tus datos han sido guardados correctamente!</h2>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                $('#message').append("<a href='index.php?action=see'>Ver usuarios registrados</a>");
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});

runOnLoad(function(){
$("input#name").select().focus();
});
```

---

¿Exactamente qué este '`$.Ajax`' ? Tenía entendido que se usaba para registrar en una base de datos y sustituir el insertar del php, pero parece que no es así. En url, veo que esta '`register.php`', pero entonces es que lo estamos llamando al documento donde esta el script como si fuese un include? Por que no veo que este pasando alguna información hacia allá con el AJAX.

En data, es igual a una variable declarada,pero la misma estructura de la variable `(var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&password=' + password;)` no logro comprenderla, en otros ejemplos he visto son bastante más diferentes, como éste `(var data= 'valor': valor1)` o sea la estructura la encuentro muy diferente, cuando usa una y cuando la otra o por que?

---

```
/// register.php
<?php
$name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'password');
mysql_select_db("tu_base_de_datos", $con);

$insert = "INSERT INTO tu_tabla (name, password, date_add) VALUES 
('$name', '$password', now())";
mysql_query($insert);
?>
```

Primera vez que veo el `mysql_query($insert);` en un archivo php, tiene que ver esto algo con ajax?

Comment: https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/usando-ajax-un-simple-ejemplo-con-php-y-jquery.html

Comment: el `mysql_query($insert);` en tu script php lo que hace es hacer uso del gestor de base de datos mysql, es decir ejecuta tu consulta sql que la almacenas en `$insert` ,de manera que **mysql_query()** no tiene nada que ver con ajax ya que ajax es para enviar datos al servidor de manera asincrona , y mysql_query es para otra cosa que no viene al caso.

Comment: Aclaro también que mysql_query() está obsoleto.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a tratar de responder tus preguntas:

**¿Exactamente qué es este '$.Ajax' ?**

$.ajax (y no $.Ajax) es la implementación de [ajax](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) hecha con [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), que es una bibloteca de JavaScript. En pocas palabras ajax es una técnica que usa el objeto XMLHttpRequest de Javascript para hacer peticiones http (POST, GET, etc..) asíncronas, en términos prácticos significa que te permite hacer peticiones sin volver a cargar la página (el DOM técnicamente). En este caso particular ese ajax esta haciendo una petición POST a register.php y le está mandando información al mismo.

**estamos llamando al documento donde esta el script como si fuese un include?**

Estamos llamando al documento como lo haría el navegador por ejemplo, estamos *ejecutando* el archivo, pero mandandole parámetros en este caso.

**La variable data**

La variable `data` está encodeando dos variables, que serían `name` y `password` de la forma querystring, que es la forma en la que internamente se pasan variables por http y es `variable1=valor1&variable2=valor2` a veces la estructura es diferente porque jquery acepta otros tipos, podría ser JSON por ejemplo, como `data : {propiedad:valor}` eso depende de lo que convenga o lo que sea mas mantenible.

**register.php**

El archivo php está *capturando* los valores enviados porque estos son guardados en la variable superglobal `$_POST` y los inserta en la base de datos (sin validar, lo que es una muy mala práctica)

Answer (score 2):

Vayamos por partes:

Cuando uno aprende php normalemente las primeras cosas que se suelen enseñar suelente ser mandar un formulario a otro fichro `.php`  o a si mismo y a interpretar estos datos, si ya has realizado esto habras notado que cada vez que esto ocurre la pagina se refresca o se redireciona, por lo tanto surge una pregunta:

> *Como se mandan o reciben datos sin la necesidad de refrescar la pagina??*
>   
> -Aqui es donde surge el procedimiento [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

Para ponerlo simple: Ajax un procedimiento asincrono que nos permite recibir o enviar informacion en segundo plano en una pagina. Lo cual trae muchos beneficios:

- Recargar datos especificos de una pagina sin necesidad de refrescarla
- Cargar la pagina y solicitar el resto de los datos despues
- Enviar datos en segundo plano

En cada lenguaje tiene una estructura, el que indicas es la peticion general que implementa jQuery ya que puedes hacerla de 3 formas generales:

1. [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) Funcion utilizada para una peticion ajax para el envio de datos
2. [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) Funcion utilizada para una peticion ajax para recibir datos
3. [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Peticion general en la que indicas dentro de los parametros si sera POST o GET

Para una peticion `GET` basica necesitas indicar 2 parametros :

- `url`: La direccion del fichero .php o la url del servidor del cual vas a recibir informacion
- `type`: En el cual indicas si es `POST` o `GET`

Si es una peticion `POST` necesitas usar el parametro `data` en el cual le envias la informacion, ejemplo:

```
data: {"username": "juan"}
```

---

```
 success: function() {};
```

Se utiliza para realizar una accion si todo se ha realizado correctamente.

En este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185686/obtener-variable-desde-archivo-php-importarla-y-usarla-en-ajax/185724#185724) tienes ejemplos de como puedes ejectuar peticiones AJAX tipo GET o POST a tus ficheros PHP y las formas de pasar datos entre ellos.

---

En lo que respecta a `register.php` es simplemente un fichero php preparado para recibir peticion `POST`, recoger los datos de dicha peticion e insertarlos en una base de datos. Eso si, lo unico que tiene que ver con AJAX es que se ha preparado para usar para ese proposito porque dentro no tiene nada de AJAX